# Position-absolute jquery inline form validation error box positon

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I am using [Positon-Absolute's jQuery inline form validation](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/).

However I am not happy with the position of the error box, I would rather it sat next to the input box rather than above it. The jquery inserts the div above the input. [Here is the demo](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html).

Any ideas on how I can position it like this?

Comment: It is very difficult to formulate an answer without even knowing what your form currently looks like.

Comment: @Asad I have listed the demo url in my description. [link]http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html[/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be achieved by overriding their css for classes responsible for displaying the error messages.